# Convert php array to javascript array with select2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2

I have the following php array in a laravel variable called `$salaries` which is passed to a blade view:

```
array:4 [▼
   2 => "£8, Per hour"
   3 => "£10, Per hour"
   23 => "Up to £10000, Per annum"
   24 => "£10,000 - £15,000, Per annum"
]
```

In my blade view I have a drop which when changed, I want to load a select2 dropdown with the above options. Below is my code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".js-selector", function() {

     var options = {!! json_encode($salaries) !!};

     $("#salary_list").empty().select2({
        data: options
     });

})
```

However nothing is getting loaded into the dropdown. So I've narrowed it down to the options data for select2 not being in the correct format.

When I output options variable to console I'm getting the following object as opposed to a javascript array?

```
{2: "£8, Per hour", 3: "£10, Per hour", 23: "Up to £10000, Per annum", 24: "£10,000 - £15,000, Per annum"}
```

How do I transform the options into correct format for the select2 data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to transform your data to the correct format, [here](https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays#loading-array-data) you can see the correct data format:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 2,
        text: '£8, Per hour'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: '£10, Per hour'
    }
];
```

You could pass the array in the correct format to the view, something like:

```
$salaries = \App\Models\Salary::all(); // eloquent collection

$salaries = $salaries->map(function ($salary) {
    return ['id' => $salary->id, 'text' => $salary->text];
})->toArray();
```

It would give result in something like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "text" => "£8, Per hour"
  ]
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "text" => "£10, Per hour"
  ]
]
```

Or you can transform the array in javascript, the Select2 documentation explains [here](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#transforming-data-into-the-required-format) how you can transform your data:

> Select2 requires that the id property is used to uniquely identify the
>   options that are displayed in the results list. If you use a property
>   other than id (like pk) to uniquely identify an option, you need to
>   map your old property to id before passing it to Select2.
>
> If you cannot do this on your server or you are in a situation where
>   the API cannot be changed, you can do this in JavaScript before
>   passing it to Select2:

```
var data = $.map(yourArrayData, function (obj) {
  obj.id = obj.id || obj.pk; // replace pk with your identifier

  return obj;
});
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".js-selector", function() {

    var options = {!! json_encode($salaries) !!};

    var data = $.map(options, function (value, key) {
        return {id: key, text: value};
    });

    $("#salary_list").empty().select2({
        data: data
    });

})
```

Comment: i'm unable to transform on the server so how to do I loop through `{2: "£8, Per hour", 3: "£10, Per hour", 23: "Up to £10000, Per annum", 24: "£10,000 - £15,000, Per annum"}` with javascript to get it in correct format?

Comment: so this is not a php, but javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

Your array must have the structure like this:

```php
[
   [
        'id' => 2,
        'text' => "£8, Per hour"
   ],
   [
        'id' => 3,
        'text' => "£10, Per hour"
   ],
   [
        'id' => 23,
        'text' => "Up to £10000, Per annum"
   ],
   [
        'id' => 24,
        'text' => "£10,000 - £15,000, Per annum"
   ],
]
```

https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays

Comment: the keys are important as they are the option values and the salary text is the option label

Comment: So your array must have this structure:
```php
[
["id' => 2,
"text" => "£8, Per hour"]
]
```
https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays

Answer (score 0):

exactly as Serhii said, simply extract the values from you associative array before encoding it:

```
$(document).on("change", ".js-selector", function() {

     var options = {!! json_encode(array_values($salaries)) !!};

     $("#salary_list").empty().select2({
        data: options
     });

})
```

Comment: they keys are important as they form the option values and the salary text is the option label.